# Proper syntax of dynamic vba range selector

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some issues with my dynamic range selector.

*I've found some other ways of implementation, but for clarity's sake I was unable to find this method of range selecting described and I'm genuinely curious as to why it's not working:*

As a test, I want to change color of a range  `Range(B20:D25)`.

With the following code

```
Private Sub colortest()
  Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

  For i = 20 to 25
    ws.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(166, 166, 166)
  Next i

End Sub
```

Basically I want to go row by row based on indices *(dynamic row indices in my actual code, hence this algorthytm with for loop, i need to go row by row as some rows can be skipped)* and then fill the Range with color.

So the expected result would be

[image]

I get the following error:

[image]

I presume it has something to do with me using the `.Range("Bi:Di")` selector incorrectly.

Comment: `Interior.Color`... you are mixing up syntax. `ColorIndex` doesn't use RGB.

Comment: Damn you're right, actually the out of Range error was caused by me using the RGB color-coding. The algorhytm / syntax in question works. 

Maybe as a sidequestion then, is there a way of using RGB colors for the `.ColorIndex`  property?

Comment: No, but why do you want to, just use Color?

Comment: Ah alright. I presumed the `.Color` property works like the one in css (so font color in other words).

Comment: This page may not be completely up to date but has quite a few examples http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector actually works fine.

Subscript out of range error was actually caused by me trying to combine `.ColorIndex` property with RGB Color-coding.

The line should have looked like either:

`ws.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15`

or

`ws.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)`